# Illegal Argument Exception for @JSONString annotation in Cloud Endpoints generated code

Tags: java, python, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm working on a Google Cloud Endpoint web service and after finally getting the auth to work, I'm having some issues with the generated code.

I've built my ProtoRPC message like this, using an Integer field for the object id, client_id and high_water_mark.

```
class NoteMessage(messages.Message):
    id = messages.IntegerField(1)
    client_id = messages.IntegerField(2)
    high_water_mark = messages.IntegerField(5)
    ...
```

This generates Java source that includes the `@JsonString` attribute on the `long` fields, but when I get a response from the server, I get the following error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: number type formatted as a JSON number cannot use @JsonString annotation [key id, field private java.lang.Long com.google.api.services.notes.model.NoteApiMessagesNoteMessage.id]
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:599)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:350)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:586)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseArray(JsonParser.java:456)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:549)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:350)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:586)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:289)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:76)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:71)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:495)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:465)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at com.ryanharter.hashnote.sync.SyncAdapter.syncNotes(SyncAdapter.java:187)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at com.ryanharter.hashnote.sync.SyncAdapter.onPerformSync(SyncAdapter.java:110)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9231):    at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:254)
```

I can't seem to find any places where I actually have control over the serialization or deserialization, so how is this supposed to work with Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124744/illegalargumentexception-deserializing-generated-objects-with-jsonstring-annot), this is caused by a quirk of the `protorpc` library. Google's API client libraries expect `int64` and `uint64` fields to be strings in JSON since Javascript itself can only handle (due to precision) integers up to `2**53`.

As you can see in the [type-format documentation](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/type-format) for Google's "Discovery" API standard, this is what to expect for these types. However, the `protorpc` library doesn't [currently use](https://code.google.com/p/google-protorpc/source/browse/python/protorpc/protojson.py) the same semantics, and we are still determining the correct way to proceed.

So, when you use

```
id = messages.IntegerField(1)
```

you are using the default variant for `IntegerField`s which is `messages.Variant.INT64`. This in turn makes the Java client library expect a JSON string such as

```
{'id': '123456789'}
```

when instead the response returned from `protorpc` is

```
{'id': 123456789}
```

As a temporary work-around for your application, either use

```
id = messages.IntegerField(1, variant=messages.Variant.INT32)
```

or if the size of your IDs need to exceed 32 bits, use:

```
id = messages.StringField(1)
```

## POST-SCRIPT:

While you're at it, I recommend looking at the [Endpoints Proto Datastore API](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/). We've done a few [screencasts](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wNRUd9E1jM) on it's use.

To solve the same issue with `endpoints-proto-datastore`, you'd import

```
from protorpc import messages
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsVariantIntegerProperty
```

and use

```
attr1 = EndpointsVariantIntegerProperty(variant=messages.Variant.INT32)
```

for your property.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bossylobster, that's exactly what I needed. I had found that other post which explained why it was happening, I just didn't know how to fix it.  Much Appreciated!